# Python-Telegram-Bot use multiple callback_data data when using InlineKeyboard?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Hello I want to pass multiple data in callback_data(`list`,`json`,`dict` anything) when using InlineKeyboard
like this:

```
def help_command(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    update.message.reply_text("Use /start to test this bot.")
    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("Test", callback_data=['1','2'])]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    update.message.reply_text('Please choose:', reply_markup=reply_markup)
```

Any solution to solve this problem and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible in telegram, the data type supported by callback is a byte of size 64. Which may also not big enough for the data you are sending.

A wise choice is to initiate a global dictionary and add your data as value and user id as key.

example:

...declare a dictionary on the top of the file....

```
TINY_DB = {}
```

...add...

```
global TINY_DB

TINY_DB[chat_id] = ["this is my big data", 1, 2, "another data"]
```

...retrive...

```
if chat_id in TINY_DB: .... no data

else data = TINY_DB[chat_id]
```